# LZW Decompress: Why is first dictionary code encountered in TIFF strip 261 instead of 257, or am I misreading it?

Tags: tiff, lzw

I have a trivial RGB file saved as TIFF in Photoshop, 1000 or so pixels wide. The first row consists of 3 pixels all of which are hex 4B red, B0 green, 78 blue, and the rest of the row white.

The strip is LZW-encoded and the initial bytes of the strip are:

**80 12 D6 07 80 04 16 0C B4 27 A1 E0 D0 B8 64 36 ...** (actually only the first 7 or so bytes are significant to my question.)

In 9-bit segments this is:

```
 100000000  001001011  010110000  001111000  000000000  100000101  100000110  ...
  (0x100)     (0x4B)     (0xB0)     (0x78)     (0x00)    (0x105)    (0x106)
```

From what I understand 256 (0x100) is a reset code, but why is the first extended code after that 261 (0x105) instead of 257? I would expect whatever dictionary entry this points to to be the 4B/B0 pair for the second pixel (which it may well be), but how would the decompression algorithm know to place 4B/B0 at 261 instead of 257? Can someone explain what I'm missing here? Might there be something elsewhere in the .tif file that would indicate this? Thanks very much.
~

Comment: The LZW encoder is always generating longer strings of the last characters emitted. The 0x105 code is the next logical code which represents the string of the last 4 characters. It is how you repeat the first 4-byte pixel. A lower valued code would be a partial string (less than 4 bytes) or an incomplete pixel.

Comment: @BitBank - thank you - makes sense now. I should have worked it through further...

Answer (score 1):

Let's see

```
256 (100h) is Clear
257 (101h) is EOF
```

in your case, then

```
4Bh B0h is 258 (102h)
B0h 78h is 259 (103h)
78h 00h is 260 (104h)
00h 00h is 261 (105h)
```

Looks good to me. LZW can actually encode one character ahead of what's been added to the table.

Comment: Thanks...evidently I have to look ahead (indefinitely?) until the code in question is inserted in the dictionary. That didn't appear to be necessary when walking through the pseudo-code I came across. This'll work now. OT - trying to up vote but "need reputation level 15?" to do so? Is there a way to acknowledge this? Thanks again...

Comment: I was not aware that you needed a certain rep level to up-vote, I don't remember that far back :) - no matter, you can come back some other time and do it if you like.

Comment: Maybe someone out there with no particular interest in this subject can cast a proxy vote for me then? :)

Comment: @haraldK - Thanks, just did so - didn't know it was that easy - wish my real life rep was that easy to bump up :)